# How can I combine several versions of IE, Mozilla browsers on the same workstation?

Tags: installation, browser

I have to check web-page with different versions of popular web-browsers. I'm not very fond of  idea to install every browser one by one (as they replace each other). Is there another way to have several versions of the same browser installed?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is capable of being installed multiple times and is as simple as installing it to a unique folder each time. Chrome is capable of doing this as well I believe...but I have not tested it. IE will likely require the use of VMs, especially for older versions if you're running, for example, Windows 7 and need to use something like IE7.

Answer (score 1):

**[Browser Sandbox](http://spoon.net/browsers/)** is very useful for this.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes you have cloud services like

http://www.browserstack.com/
https://saucelabs.com/home

If you prefer local testing this free VM's are unbeatable, just one click to get them installed

http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools